# Pharo stdout closed randomly

Tags: pharo

I'm running a fairly long running task in a headless instance of Pharo 3 on Linux and sometimes (seemingly randomly) i get the following

```
FileWriteError: File stdout is closed
MultiByteFileStream(StandardFileStream)>>primWrite:from:startingAt:count:
MultiByteFileStream(StandardFileStream)>>next:putAll:startingAt:
MultiByteFileStream>>basicNext:putAll:startingAt:
UTF8TextConverter(TextConverter)>>nextPutByteString:toStream:
UTF8TextConverter(TextConverter)>>nextPutAll:toStream:
MultiByteFileStream>>nextPutAll:
ArgumentDataGatherer(Object)>>printOn:
MultiByteFileStream(Stream)>>print:
VTermOutputDriver>>print:
EvaluateCommandLineHandler>>evaluate: in Block: [ ...
BlockClosure>>on:do:
EvaluateCommandLineHandler>>evaluate:
EvaluateCommandLineHandler>>evaluateArguments
EvaluateCommandLineHandler>>activate
EvaluateCommandLineHandler class(CommandLineHandler class)>>activateWith:
PharoCommandLineHandler(BasicCommandLineHandler)>>activateSubCommand: in Block: [ aCommandLinehandler activateWith: commandLine ]
BlockClosure>>on:do:
PharoCommandLineHandler(BasicCommandLineHandler)>>activateSubCommand:
PharoCommandLineHandler(BasicCommandLineHandler)>>handleSubcommand
...
```

And Pharo crashes.

Any idea why this might be happening or how to fix it?

Comment: This might occur if you exceed the maximum number of file handles for the process / for the system. Can you post the code which opens and closes the stream?

Comment: It's stdout. I don't open or close it :D

Comment: I see that. But you don't say what else you're doing with files (e.g. repeatedly open file for logging or the like).

Comment: Absolutely nothing. I store all data into a mongoDB and I log some progress information to stdout via Transcript.

Comment: Hm. Might be a VM problem then. Could you provide a little more context? I.e. code to reproduce the problem with (if possible), a minimal example of code to execute (replace what's not needed with a commented), OS version, VM version... I can then forward your problem to the vm devs.

Comment: The sad thing is that I cannot reproduce it easily. It is a fairly long running task that does a whole bunch of things, and the FileWriteError seems to happen at random times. I'll try to find a nice way to reproduce it, but I have no idea where to start :) quite the heisenbug.